# Annihilation operator of a particle at $\bf x$ for canonically qauntized Klein Gordon field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, field-theory

I am now reading the David Tong's lecture notes on quantum field theory.

http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/two.pdf

And I have some questions on whether there is some **well-defined particle annihilation operator at position $\bf x$.**

I already know that we can interpret $\phi ({\bf x}) \left| {0} \right\rangle$ as a single-particle state at position $\bf x$. However, it seems that we can not say that $\phi ({\bf x})$ is the creation operator for a particle at $\bf x$. This is because it is a real scalar field which satisfies $\phi ^{\dagger} ({\bf x}) = \phi ({\bf x})$. Therefore, if we try to interpret $\phi ({\bf x})$ as the particle creation operator then we will totally get lost of the corresponding particle annihilation operator at $\bf x$.

Therefore I am confused, is there any particle annihilation operator at position $\bf x$ in this rather simple real scalar field theory?

I would be grateful for any suggestion! Thanks!

Comment: In spite of what Tong is saying, we **cannot** interpret $\phi(\boldsymbol x)|0\rangle$ as a single-particle state at position $\boldsymbol x$. That's a lie to the children that doesn't hold up.

Comment: Oh really? Then what is the proper interpretation of the state $\phi ({\bf x}) \left| {0} \right\rangle$? Thanks! 

Btw in Peskin's book it is stated that "We will therefore put forward
the same interpretation and claim that the operator $\phi ({\bf x})$ acting on the vacuum creates a particle at position $\bf x$"

Comment: No interpretation whatsoever. It's just a mathematical tool. Broadly speaking, the only object with a physical interpretation is the $S$-matrix. This object can be calculated using $\phi(\boldsymbol x)$; but $\phi(\boldsymbol x)$ itself has no meaning.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform In a free quantum field theory, everything is properly defined, and it makes perfect sense to interpret the elements of the $n$-particle sectors of the Fock space as wavefunctions describing $n$ particles. In fact there is a very explicit characterization of the dynamics (or action of the Poincaré group if you prefer) in such case, that fits very well with such interpretation.

Comment: For interacting theories that are non-Fock, such as the few ones we know how to deal with mathematically in low dimensions, then the Fock vectors and free fields do not have much physical meaning (since the canonical observables are not represented in Fock space). The interacting fields and vacuum state should instead be considered.

Comment: @yuggib "It makes perfect sense" is a meaningless statement if you don't specify what you mean by that. You could say "it makes sense" and I could say "it doesn't", but that wouldn't take us anywhere. What properties of $\phi(\boldsymbol x)|0\rangle$ suggest that such a state looks like a particle at $\boldsymbol x$?

Comment: For example, the action of the Poincaré group (associated to the free scalar field) on the one-particle sector of the Fock space is irreducible and leaves it invariant. To this irreducible induced representation are associated a mass $m$ and a spin (zero) of the given particle. Since the distribution $\varphi(x)\Omega$ maps test functions into vectors of the Fock space whose only non-zero component is the one-particle one, it can be effectively interpreted as a map (distribution) to wavefunctions describing one particle.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform in free QFT, S-matrix is identity by definition. However there’s still plenty of physical content. E.g. wavepackets corresponding to multiparticle configurations propagate with time (and it is possible to calculate this propagation for finite time intervals, which S-matrix doesn’t care about). The interpretation of $\phi$ as creating a single-particle state is not perfect, but for different reasons (coordinate space wavefuncrions make sense on scales larger than the Compton wavelength).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform also no real experiment corresponds to a situation, for which S-matrix can be employed, simply because those experiments happen in a finite period of time. We shouldn’t confuse not being able to compute anything meaningful besides the S-matrix with there not being such an object. E.g. lattice QCD, from what I hear, computes dynamics of the real theory in finite time intervals, and not just the S-matrix.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus We'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform allrighty, but would you mind  saying that an alternative opinion exists (and is also quite popular among theorists) when you are answering a question then?

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus I didn't answer any question.

Answer (score 1):

The Fock representation of the free field operator (valued distribution) $\varphi(x)$ can be written as the sum $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(a^*(x)+a(x))$, where $a(x)$ and $a^*(x)$ are the annihilation and creation operator( valued distribution)s on the Fock space.

Since the acting on the vacuum $\Omega$, $a(x)$ satisfies $a(x)\Omega=0$, it then follows that $\varphi(x)\Omega= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}a^*(x)\Omega$, that is a Fock space vector (valued distribution) belonging to the sector with only one particle ("localized" at position $x$).

Alternatively, one could also define the field momentum operator (valued distribution) $\pi(x)$, satisfying the usual canonical commutation relation with $\varphi(x)$: $[\varphi(x),\pi(y)]=i\delta(x-y)$. Then $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\varphi + i\pi)$ and $a^*=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\varphi-i\pi)$.

Comment: Sorry, but how does this answer the question "is there any particle annihilation operator at position $\boldsymbol x$ in this rather simple real scalar field theory?" You only described how $a^*(x)$ creates a particle at $x$ (which OP already knows), but you didn't say anything about annihilating something at $x$.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform The answer is in the last paragraph (where the annihilation operator is defined in terms of the field and field momentum operators). However I admit that I have not given much details. Being more precise, it is always possible, in the Fock representation of the canonical commutation relations, to introduce (starting from the canonical observables) the annihilation and creation operators, and to check their usual properties that can be interpreted as annihilation and creation of *free* particles.